# infinix smart 7 stuck in bootloop after root x6515 (recovery mod not entering power + volume up/down)

Tags: rooted-device

have a rooted Smart 7 (X6515) phone and attempted to change its "IMEI" number. However, I encountered difficulties and decided to flash it using TWRP in fastboot mode. Unfortunately, my phone is now stuck in a boot loop and I have been unsuccessful in entering recovery mode by using the power button with the volume up key. Could someone assist me in entering recovery mode so that I can install a new ROM on my phone?

my phone is stuck in a boot loop, Using power of + volume up / down, is not working the boot loop is still